# How to statically detect bugs that are being introduced because of a code change?

Tags: c-preprocessor, static-analysis

I have a large codebase written mostly in C language with several enums. Recently I modified one of the enums and it had a major impact because I somewhat "mis"-estimated the impact.
There was an enum which looked like this :-

```
typedef enum en_e_type
{
ENUM_VAL_1 = 1,
ENUM_VAL_2 = 2,
ENUM_VAL_3 = 3,
ENUM_VAL_MAX = 4,
}en_e;
```

This got changed to

```
typedef enum en_e_type
{
ENUM_VAL_1 = 1,
ENUM_VAL_2 = 2,
ENUM_VAL_3 = 3,
ENUM_VAL_MAX = ENUM_VAL_3 ,
}en_e;
```

We can see that the value of `ENUM_VAL_MAX` got modified.
There were some asserts in my code which looked like this

```
ASSERT (in_value < ENUM_VAL_MAX )
```

And some if conditions like this :-

```
if (in_val < ENUM_VAL_MAX)
```

We were expecting `in_value < ENUM_VAL_MAX` always and with the new enum change, the `asserts` and the if conditions should have been modified accordingly but some of these were missed out and hence the problem.

My question is, what is the best way to identify these kind of bugs ? Is there some static analyzer tool which looks at the code diff and accordingly analyzes its impact ? For ex. in this case, is there a tool which would potentially point me to these `if/assert` conditions (by statically parsing the code) and emit some warning ? I looked at Helgrind but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to hear this, but:

1. An assert should be based on documented behavior. In this case, there should've been a summary above the enum value saying that ENUM_VAL_MAX is bigger than any of the preceding values.
2. When refactoring, always do a right click -> check references (most IDE's have this option) and scroll through it. You'll see the line of the code it's being used in, in the overview and as such you would've detected the comparisons.